# Custom Fade Segue not animating if I present the destinationViewController

Tags: ios, swift, animation, segue

I've written a custom segue to get a fade effect, which i'm trying to achieve by inserting the `destination view controller` below the `source view controller` and animating the `alpha` of the `source view controller` to zero.

However, adding the `destination view controller` below the source seems to cancel the animation and the segue performs as if it is a regular `present` with animation disabled.

```
import UIKit

class FadeSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        // Get the view of the source
        let sourceViewControllerView = self.sourceViewController.view
        // Get the view of the destination
        let destinationViewControllerView = self.destinationViewController.view

        let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

        // Make the destination view the size of the screen
        destinationViewControllerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)

        if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow {
            // Insert destination below the source
            // Without this line the animation works but the transition is not smooth as it jumps from white to the new view controller
            window.insertSubview(destinationViewControllerView, belowSubview: sourceViewControllerView)

            // Animate the fade, remove the destination view on completion and present the full view controller
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
                sourceViewControllerView.alpha = 0.0
                }, completion: { (finished) in
                    destinationViewControllerView.removeFromSuperview()
                    self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure will it give the same result, but you can try to set destinationViewControllerView.alpha = 0.0 and then change its alpha to 1.0 in animation block, in this case you don't need to call window.insertSubview(destinationViewControllerView, belowSubview: sourceViewControllerView) before animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello I think that what you need is this

```
override func perform() {
        // Get the view of the source
        let sourceViewControllerView = self.sourceViewController.view
        // Get the view of the destination
        let destinationViewControllerView = self.destinationViewController.view

        let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

        // Make the destination view the size of the screen
        destinationViewControllerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)

            // Insert destination below the source
            // Without this line the animation works but the transition is not smooth as it jumps from white to the new view controller
            destinationViewControllerView.alpha = 0;
            sourceViewControllerView.addSubview(destinationViewControllerView);
            // Animate the fade, remove the destination view on completion and present the full view controller
            UIView.animateWithDuration(10, animations: {
                destinationViewControllerView.alpha = 1;
                }, completion: { (finished) in
                    destinationViewControllerView.removeFromSuperview()
                    self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
            })
        }
    }
```

I Hope this help you

Comment: I got an error "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions" with the above answer. The solution was to not remove the destination view in the completion closure.

Answer (score 4):

The slightly modified Swift 4.1 compatible solution based on the answer from @reinier-melian

```
/// Performs a simple fade between source and destination view controller.
class Fade: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {

        guard let destinationView = self.destination.view else {
            // Fallback to no fading
            self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: nil)
            return
        }

        destinationView.alpha = 0
        self.source.view?.addSubview(destinationView)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: CATransaction.animationDuration(), animations: {
            destinationView.alpha = 1
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing for my purposes. It puts a `placeholder view` with basic ui elements over the top once all the on screen things have animated out and fades in the placeholder, then presents the `destination view controller` and removes the `placeholder`. The `destination view controller` then animates in all its elements, essentially making the transition invisible and looks like one single animation:

```
import UIKit

class FadeSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    var placeholderView: UIViewController?

    override func perform() {
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

        if let placeholder = placeholderView {
            placeholder.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)

            placeholder.view.alpha = 0
            sourceViewController.view.addSubview(placeholder.view)

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
                placeholder.view.alpha = 1
                }, completion: { (finished) in
                    self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController, animated: false, completion: {
                        placeholder.view.removeFromSuperview()
                    })
            })
        } else {
            self.destinationViewController.view.alpha = 0.0

            self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController, animated: false, completion: {
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
                    self.destinationViewController.view.alpha = 1.0
                })
            })
        }
    }
}
```

and the unwind:

```
import UIKit

class FadeSegueUnwind: UIStoryboardSegue {

    var placeholderView: UIViewController?

    override func perform() {
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

        if let placeholder = placeholderView {
            placeholder.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)

            placeholder.view.alpha = 0
            sourceViewController.view.addSubview(placeholder.view)
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
                placeholder.view.alpha = 1
                }, completion: { (finished) in
                    self.sourceViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
            })
        } else {
            self.destinationViewController.view.alpha = 0.0

            self.sourceViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: { 
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { 
                    self.destinationViewController.view.alpha = 0.0
                })
            })
        }
    }
}
```